# pass a List<Guid> to action method as Json issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am having some issues building a Json string of guids to pass to my action  method.

I have collected my guids into an array like this:

```
var regEx = /^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/;
        var arrJson = {};
        var i = 0;
        $('#destGrid tr').each(function () {
            $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                var td = $(this);
                if (regEx.test(td[0].innerText)) {
                    arrJson[i] = td[0].innerText;
                    i++;
                }
            });
        });
```

I then use json.stringify on the array, and give it the param name that the action method takes.

```
if (arrJson[0] != null) {
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ selectedMatters: arrJson });
```

at this point, if I debug the javaScript, I can inspect the value of the string, and I can see all the quotes have been escaped:

```
"{\"selectedMatters\":{\"0\":\"f7c918d6-4e40-e211-9854-00155d010d00\",\"1\":\"77d4d836-ce45-e211-9854-00155d010d00\",\"2\":\"c6849622-cf45-e211-9854-00155d010d00\",\"3\":\"0ce4dc5b-cf45-e211-9854-00155d010d00\"}}"
```

for completeness the method signature looks like this:

```
public bool UpdateMattersForGrid(List<Guid> selectedMatters)
{
}
```

I have tried a number of things, but most of the time selectedMatters is null. Can anyone explain why this is not picked up be the model binding, and how I can correct it. Other example I have found simply tell me to do what I am currently doing.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to maintain the order of the GUIDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change from a javascript object `{}` to a javascript array `[]`.  This will map to `List<>`.

So the javascript would look something like this:

```
var regEx = /^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/;
        var arrJson = [];  //change to array
        var i = 0;
        $('#destGrid tr').each(function () {
            $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                var td = $(this);
                if (regEx.test(td[0].innerText)) {
                    arrJson.push(td[0].innerText);  // push into array
                    i++;
                }
            });
        });
```